# .getTime() returning strange results

Tags: javascript

I have the following set-up, and getting a strange result from the date.getTime() function:

```
this.state.model = {
  start_date: '2019-10-13',
  end_date: '2019-10-15'
}

let startDate: Date = new Date(new 
Date(this.state.model.start_date).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: 
  "America/Los_Angeles"}));

let endDate: Date = new Date(new 
  Date(this.state.model.end_date).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: 
  "America/Los_Angeles"}));
```

Here is the output:

```
console.log src/components/meal/MealEditor.tsx:44
start: 1570924800000 | 2019-10-13T00:00:00.000Z

console.log src/components/meal/MealEditor.tsx:45
end: 1287100800000 | 2010-10-15T00:00:00.000Z
```

Here the .getTime() function is returning a lower number for 10/13 than it is for 10/15.

Am I setting this up incorrectly?

Comment: You seem to be comparing two different years in your actual code. Seems like a typo. `2010 < 2019`

Comment: Yes, it seems like it shows bad data, but it's actually correct output for your current code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

you may doing sth. other mistake..
your problem is not with getTime()

```
var start = new Date('2019-10-13');
console.log(start.getTime()); //1570924800000

var end = new Date('2019-10-15');
console.log(end.getTime()); //1571097600000


let startDate = new Date(new 
Date('2019-10-13').toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"}));
console.log(startDate); //> Sat Oct 12 2019 17:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)


let endDate = new Date(new Date('2019-10-15').toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"}));
console.log(endDate); //> Mon Oct 14 2019 17:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```